# /usr/bin/top OS X 10.15.7 takes 15 seconds to start then uses 33% CPU

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, top

OS X 10.13 `/usr/bin/top` would start instantly and takes a couple % CPU at best.  After upgrading to 10.15.7 Catalina, it takes literally 15 seconds for the proc info to come up and it is at the top of of its own list at 33% CPU.   Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

A system dialog popped up and said I was about to run out of Application Memory and to shut down unneeded app.   I closed Xcode and the Simulator.
`top` now starts in less than 1 second and only takes 3% CPU.
I think the machine was under considerable stress but I was only doing editing in emacs and `scp/ssh` and without the fan blaring away as a warning I did not know it.